# wpbakery custom element nested if else condition

Tags: php, wordpress, wpbakery

i am trying to create custom element for wpbakery and i am new to this things.
i creating a element which should be use for 2 different purposes i.e either user can display button or social media links. below is the code i tried :

```
      //frontend
        add_shortcode( 'expert', 'expert_func' );
        function expert_func( $atts, $content = null ) { // New function parameter $content is added!
            extract(
                shortcode_atts(
                  array(
                    'expert_image' => 'expert_image',
                    'title'   => '',
                  ),
                  $atts
                )
              );

              $img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $expert_image, "full");

              extract(
                shortcode_atts(
                  array(
                    'expert_exp_image' => 'expert_exp_image',
                    'title'   => '',
                  ),
                  $atts
                )
              );

              $exp_img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $expert_exp_image, "full");

              extract(
                shortcode_atts(
                  array(
                    'exp_btn_url' => 'exp_btn_url',
                  ),
                  $atts
                )
              );

              extract(
                shortcode_atts(
                  array(
                    'Twitter' => 'Twitter',
                    'Facebook' => 'Facebook',
                    'Linkedn' => 'Linkedn',
                    'Instagram' => 'Instagram',
                  ),
                  $atts
                )
              );

             $btn_link = '';


            $result .='<div class="inner__card">
                        <div class="expert-img">
                          <img src="'. $img_url[0] .'">
                        </div>
                        <div class="expert-details">
                          <p class="name">'.$atts['expert_name'].'</p>
                          <p class="designation">'.$atts['expert_designation'].'</p>
                          <div class="expect-experience">
                            <div class="expect-experience-no">
                              <img src="'. $exp_img_url[0] .'" alt="experience-10">
                            </div>
                            <div class="expect-experience-text">
                              <p>'.$atts['expert_short_desc'].'</span></p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <p class="details">'.$atts['expert_description'].'</p>';
                          if($exp_btn_url!=''){
            $result .='<div class="expert-btn">';
                       if ($exp_btn_url) {
                           $exp_btn_url = vc_build_link($exp_btn_url);
                           $a_href = $exp_btn_url['url'];
                           $a_title = $exp_btn_url['title'];
                           $a_target = $exp_btn_url['target'];
                           $icon_box_link = array('href="' . esc_attr($a_href) . '"', 'title="' . esc_attr($a_title) . '"', 'target="' . esc_attr($a_target) . '"');
                           $btn_link = '<a class="learn-btn" ' . implode(' ', $icon_box_link) . '>' . esc_attr($a_title) . '</a>';
                       }

             $result .= $btn_link;
           }
            $result .= '<a href="'.$exp_btn_url.'" class="learn-btn">Learn More</a>';
                        }
         else{
                      $result .='<div class="card-socail">
                        <div class="social-buttons"> 
                        <!-- TwitterButton -->
                          <a href="'.$atts['Twitter'].'" target="blank" class="social-margin">
                            <div class="social-icon twitter">
                              <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div> 
                          </a>       
                          <!-- facebook  Button -->
                          <a href="'.$atts['Facebook'].'" target="blank" class="social-margin"> 
                            <div class="social-icon facebook">
                              <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                            </div>
                          </a>
                          <!-- LinkedIn Button -->
                          <a href="'.$atts['Linkedn'].'" class="social-margin" target="blank">
                            <div class="social-icon linkedin">
                              <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div> 
                          </a>
                          <!-- Instagram Button -->
                          <a href="'.$atts['Instagram'].'" target="blank" class="social-margin">
                            <div class="social-icon behance">
                              <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                          </a>

                        </div>
                    </div>';

                    }


        $result .=' </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>';

          //print_r($atts);

          return $result;

        }

        //backend
        add_action( 'vc_before_init', 'expert_integrateWithVC' );
        function expert_integrateWithVC() {
         vc_map( array(
          "name" => __( "Expert", "my-text-domain" ),
          "base" => "expert",
          "class" => "",
          "category" => __( "Clicksplode Elements", "my-text-domain"),
          "params" => array(
         array(
          "type" => "attach_image",
          "holder" => "div",
          "class" => "",
          "heading" => __( "Choose Expert Image", "my-text-domain" ),
          "param_name" => "expert_image",
          "value" => __( "", "my-text-domain" )

         ),
        array(
          "type" => "textfield",
          "holder" => "div",
          "class" => "",
          "heading" => __( "Expert Name", "my-text-domain" ),
          "param_name" => "expert_name",
          "value" => __( "", "my-text-domain" )
         ),
        array(
          "type" => "textfield",
          "holder" => "div",
          "class" => "",
          "heading" => __( "Expert Designation", "my-text-domain" ),
          "param_name" => "expert_designation",
          "value" => __( "", "my-text-domain" )
         ),
        array(
          "type" => "attach_image",
          "holder" => "div",
          "class" => "",
          "heading" => __( "Add Year of Expirience image", "my-text-domain" ),
          "param_name" => "expert_exp_image",
          "value" => __( "", "my-text-domain" )
         ),
        array(
          "type" => "textfield",
          "holder" => "div",
          "class" => "",
          "heading" => __( "Expert's Expirience Short Description", "my-text-domain" ),
          "param_name" => "expert_short_desc",
          "value" => __( "", "my-text-domain" )
         ),
        array(
          "type" => "textarea",
          "holder" => "div",
          "class" => "",
          "heading" => __( "Short Description of Expert", "my-text-domain" ),
          "param_name" => "expert_description",
          "value" => __( "", "my-text-domain" )
         ),
        array(
          "type" => "vc_link",
          "holder" => "div",
          "class" => "",
          "heading" => __( "Choose Rediect URL", "my-text-domain" ),
          "param_name" => "exp_btn_url",
          "value" => __( "", "my-text-domain" ),
          "description" => __( "Add Short Description", "my-text-domain" )
         ),
        array(
          "type" => "textfield",
          "holder" => "div",
          "class" => "",
          "heading" => __( "Add Twitter URL", "my-text-domain" ),
          "param_name" => "Twitter",
          "value" => __( "", "my-text-domain" )
         ),
        array(
          "type" => "textfield",
          "holder" => "div",
          "class" => "",
          "heading" => __( "Add Facebook URL", "my-text-domain" ),
          "param_name" => "Facebook",
          "value" => __( "", "my-text-domain" )
         ),
        array(
          "type" => "textfield",
          "holder" => "div",
          "class" => "",
          "heading" => __( "Add Linkedn URL", "my-text-domain" ),
          "param_name" => "Linkedn",
          "value" => __( "", "my-text-domain" )
         ),
        array(
          "type" => "textfield",
          "holder" => "div",
          "class" => "",
          "heading" => __( "Add Instagram URL", "my-text-domain" ),
          "param_name" => "Instagram",
          "value" => __( "", "my-text-domain" )
         )

          )
         ) );
        }
```

i know above code is not correct but all i want to display is if user adds url to the button than social media button should be hiden and if user adds social media links than button should be hiden.
 please find attached

[image with yellow button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8vjS.png)

[image with social media links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvDNZ.png)

Comment: This is not the right way to do. This can be helpful to you https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/How-to-create-a-custom-element-in-the-visual-composer/

Comment: code is working fine. I need help to add condition. if button url is selected hide social media icons and if social links are added hide yellow button. thats it.

Comment: Code may be working fine, but you need add an option which will help you to implement the logic. somthing like a dropdown with "social" and  "button" options. You know how to add that, if no please check the given url